# How much weight do workshop papers hold for PhD Admissions (Fall 2022 CS USA)

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, workshop

**Background:** CS undergrad applying to CS PhD programs.

I recently got a workshop (poster paper) accepted at the best conference in my domain as a third author (first three authors equal contribution, 7 in total).

**Question:** Do workshop papers hold any weight front of the PhD Admit panel?

Note: I know there are similar questions but I am asking in specific to CS undergrads applying for grad school.

Comment: Well, it's surely not going to *detract* from your application.

Comment: What are you going to do with the answer?

Comment: I'm in the process of selecting schools and there are only so many I can choose. Knowing where my profile stands will help me finalise on my decisions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctoral admission in the US is very broad based. If all of your application materials, including letters of recommendation, are consistent and show that you are hard working, observant, and have a hight likelihood of success in research then you should be fine. But the accomplishment you name won't be determinative, especially if not consistent with all the other things. It is a plus, certainly, but you need a lot of plusses in a competitive environment.

However, note that not every doctoral candidate holding only a bachelors degree in the US has much if any real research experience or publications.

But admission is a joint decision of a committee of individuals, each of which as there own ideas about who should be admitted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!